# Timer does not update labels

Tags: vb.net

In a Windows Forms application, I've got a timer with the following code:

```
Public Class SyncForm
    Public pbvalue As Integer = 0
    Public pbProcess As String = ""

    Sub DataProcess()
        pb.Value += 1
        pbProcess = "Read, match and compare"
        ...
        pb.Value += 1
        pbProcess = "Exporting..."
    End Sub

    Private Sub timerpb_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles timerpb.Tick
        pb.Value = pbValue
        lbReadProcess.Text = pbProcess
        lbReadProcess.Refresh()
        pb.PerformStep()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I start the `DataProcess` sub with a button on this form.
During the process, the progress bar is updated correctly, but the label on the form (`lbReadProcess`), that should indicate the currently running process, not. Can someone give me a hint, why not? Thanks.

Comment: Check if `pb.value` is a `string`. Parse it to `int` if it is a `string`

Comment: Off-topic, but you do not need to call `lbReadProcess.Refresh()` - unless you're doing custom painting.

Comment: Why cant you just set the label text in `DataProcess()`?  Its not like it is changing on each timer tick

Comment: Now I am more confused because obviously I misunderstood the purpose of the timer. All progressbar tutorials use the timer, so I tought that I need to call the updates from the timer. Looks like, I don't even need the timer and still, both the progressbar and the label updates are working. The key was given by the question of @conquistador, as this helped me to realise that what's happening has nothing to do with the `pbvalue` or any other variable.